# Is it "eĉ ne" or "ne eĉ"?

Tags: word-usage

For example:

*She didn't even light the candles.*

> 1) Ŝi **ne eĉ** ekbruligis la kandelojn.
>
> 2) Ŝi **eĉ ne** ekbruligis la kandelojn.

Does the placement of ***eĉ*** matter at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we follow the principle that adverbs come before the word they modify, the answer to your question comes down to a question of what needs to modify what. PIV includes a note: *Oni metas eĉ ĉiam senpere antaŭ la vorton aŭ prop-on, kiun oni volas emfazi*

With this in mind, both your alternatives make sense.

1) Ŝi ne eĉ ekbruligis la kandelojn.

2) Ŝi eĉ ne ekbruligis la kandelojn.

The difference seems to be that in number 1, there were many things she could have done to the candles and she didn't even manage to light them. In number 2, there were many tasks that she could have done and she didn't manage to light the candles.

In either event, the context would clarify the intended meaning.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look in tekstaro.com you will find hundreds of *eĉ ne* and hundreds of *ne eĉ*, which shows that they are both used.

Answer (score 4):

Comparing the google search results I would say that both of them are valid, but they are used to express a slightly different meaning.

- Ne eĉ: ~ 42 900
- Eĉ ne: ~ 233 000

For your sentence I would prefer *eĉ ne* because it sounds more natural to me.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do you make inferences about the meaning just from a difference in frequency?

Answer (score 4):

*Eĉ* should be placed right before the matter it concerns, and *ne* needs to be just before the word/fact it negates.  (see PEMG - [Plena Manlibro de Esperanto Gramatiko](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html).)

The preferred translation thus would be: *Ŝi eĉ ne ekbruligis la kandelojn*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a link to the particular part of PMEG that you're referencing. I have checked the sections of PMEG on *eĉ* and on *negado* and I don't see what it is you're trying to reference. In fact, both forms are found in the PMEG. Neither is marked as an error or not preferred that I can find.

Comment: I uzed this part of PMEG: [link](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/neado.html#i-3h5) _Ne neas tion, antaŭ kio ĝi staras._ 
I assumed, that the stress in the english fraze would be not on "even" but on "she didn't light the candles. Perhaps I should have mentioned my assumption.